# How do you only return one field when there are multiple entries for each field?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I am trying to only return one email address for each employee. An Employee can be both an employee and a student. If you have both an employee and student email address then I only want to return the employee email address else if you only have student email address then return the student email address.

Here is the entire query:

```
select --spriden_pidm                                                as pidm,
    spriden_id                                                 as ban_id,
    spriden_last_name                                          as lastname, 
    spriden_first_name                                         as firstname,
    gmal.email,
    phone_number.area || phone_number.phone                    as phone_number,
    addr.permanent_address                                          AS street,
    addr.permanent_city                                             AS city,
    addr.permanent_state                                            AS state,
    addr.permanent_zip                                              AS zip,

case
    when nbrjobs_ecls_code in ('E1', 'E2', 'EN', 'F1', 'F2') and nbrjobs_ann_salary between 0 and 49999.99 then 'EHRA1'
    when nbrjobs_ecls_code in ('E1', 'E2', 'EN', 'F1', 'F2') and nbrjobs_ann_salary between 50000 and 99999.99 then 'EHRA2'
    when nbrjobs_ecls_code in ('E1', 'E2', 'EN', 'F1', 'F2') and nbrjobs_ann_salary between 100000 and 149999.99 then 'EHRA3'
    when nbrjobs_ecls_code in ('E1', 'E2', 'EN', 'F1', 'F2') and nbrjobs_ann_salary >= 150000 then 'EHRA4'
    when nbrjobs_ecls_code in ('SE', 'SN', 'LE') and nbrjobs_ann_salary between 0 and 49999.99 then 'SHRA1'
    when nbrjobs_ecls_code in ('SE', 'SN', 'LE') and nbrjobs_ann_salary between 50000 and 99999.99 then 'SHRA2'
    when nbrjobs_ecls_code in ('SE', 'SN', 'LE') and nbrjobs_ann_salary between 100000 and 149999.99 then 'SHRA3'
    when nbrjobs_ecls_code in ('SE', 'SN', 'LE') and nbrjobs_ann_salary >= 150000 then 'SHRA4'
    when nbrjobs_ecls_code in ('FA') then 'AF'
    when nbrjobs_ecls_code in ('SH', 'SS', 'TS', 'WS') then 'M1'
else 
    null
end as empl_cat
from nbrjobs a,
     spriden,
     (select goremal_pidm as pidm,
                goremal_email_address as email
        from goremal
        where goremal_emal_code in ('EMPL', 'STDN')
         and goremal_status_ind = 'A') gmal,
     (SELECT sprtele_pidm       AS pidm,
           sprtele_phone_area   AS area,
           sprtele_phone_number AS phone
      FROM sprtele c
     WHERE     sprtele_tele_code = 'CA'
           AND sprtele_primary_ind = 'Y'
           AND sprtele_status_ind IS NULL
           AND sprtele_seqno =
                   (SELECT MAX (sprtele_seqno)
                      FROM sprtele
                     WHERE     sprtele_tele_code = 'CA'
                           AND sprtele_primary_ind = 'Y'
                           AND sprtele_status_ind IS NULL
                           AND sprtele_pidm = c.sprtele_pidm)) phone_number,
     --spraddr
     (SELECT spraddr_pidm         AS pidm,
           spraddr_street_line1 AS permanent_address,
           spraddr_city         AS permanent_city,
           spraddr_stat_code    AS permanent_state,
           spraddr_zip          AS permanent_zip
      FROM spraddr b
     WHERE     spraddr_atyp_code = 'CA'
           AND spraddr_status_ind IS NULL
           AND spraddr_seqno =
                   (SELECT MAX (spraddr_seqno)
                      FROM spraddr
                     WHERE     spraddr_atyp_code = 'CA'
                           AND spraddr_status_ind IS NULL
                           AND spraddr_pidm = b.spraddr_pidm)) addr
where a.nbrjobs_pidm = spriden_pidm
 and a.nbrjobs_pidm = gmal.pidm(+)
 and a.nbrjobs_pidm = phone_number.pidm(+)
 and a.nbrjobs_pidm = addr.pidm(+)
 and spriden_change_ind is null
 and a.nbrjobs_sgrp_code = to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') 
 and a.nbrjobs_effective_date = (select max(b.nbrjobs_effective_date) 
                                    from nbrjobs b
                                    where b.nbrjobs_pidm = a.nbrjobs_pidm
                                     and b.nbrjobs_posn = a.nbrjobs_posn
                                     and b.nbrjobs_effective_date <= sysdate
                                     --and b.nbrjobs_ecls_code in ('E1','E2','EN','F1','F2','SE','SN','LE')
                                     and b.nbrjobs_ecls_code in ('E1','E2','EN','F1','F2','SE','SN','LE', 'RF', 'AF', 'FA', 'SH', 'SS', 'TS', 'WS')
                                     and b.nbrjobs_sgrp_code = to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY'))                                    
 and a.nbrjobs_status <> 'T';`
```

and this is the part of the query I am trying to change to return the desired email address

```
(select goremal_pidm as pidm,
                goremal_email_address as email
        from goremal
        where goremal_emal_code in ('EMPL', 'STDN')
         and goremal_status_ind = 'A') gmal,
```

Comment: Your question is reasonable, but you've given us too much query and not enough detail. Mock up a sample of data from goremal with representative data in it. Post the scripts necessary for us to do the same thing. Then focus on the subquery that's of interest to you. The tools in this post will be helpful, and the distinction between t-sql (which the post talks about) and pl/sql (which you need help with) in this case don't matter much. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I don't see any mention of t-sql (which is a MSSQL product) in the question and PL/SQL is not necessary here as far as I can tell.

Comment: @DavidFaber, my error with the PL/SQL reference. You're correct.  But the post I linked to uses MS SQL in it's examples, and has T-SQL in it's title, but the instructions in that post on building out good questions, and the tools to do it, apply across most sql dialects, which was the only point I was trying to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is that the query will return two email addresses if the employee is also a student? What you can do in this case is `PIVOT` the data, then use `COALESCE()` to get the student email where the employee email is NULL. The below query would replace the problematic subquery:

```
SELECT pidm, COALESCE(empl_email, stdn_email) AS email
  FROM (
    SELECT goremal_pidm AS pidm, goremal_email_address AS email, goremal_emal_code
      FROM goremal
     WHERE goremal_emal_code in ('EMPL', 'STDN')
       AND goremal_status_ind = 'A'
) PIVOT (
    MAX(email) FOR goremal_emal_code IN ('EMPL' AS empl_email, 'STDN' AS stdn_email)
)
```

**EDIT:** As an aside, you can use conditional aggregation instead of an explicit `PIVOT` (helpful if you're using Oracle 9i or lower):

```
SELECT pidm, COALESCE(empl_email, stdn_email) AS email FROM (
    SELECT goremal_pidm AS pidm
         , MAX(CASE WHEN goremal_emal_code = 'EMPL' THEN goremal_email_address END) AS empl_email
         , MAX(CASE WHEN goremal_emal_code = 'STDN' THEN goremal_email_address END) AS stdn_email
      FROM goremal
     WHERE goremal_emal_code in ('EMPL', 'STDN')
       AND goremal_status_ind = 'A'
     GROUP BY goremal_pidm
)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using NVL2, as a example for your case -

**NVL2(EMP_EMAIL_ADR, EMP_EMAIL_ADR, STDN_EMAIL_ADR)**

This clause will return if the Employee email address is not null else it returns Student email address.

Hope this helps.

Comment: He doesn't have separate columns for employee email and student email, so the above solution will not work.